# Scrape LinkedIn connections

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape so data from LinkedIn.  I want to scrape the connections of my connections.  I've written code in Python, BeautifulSoup and Selenium that will pick up my connections and go into the connection's profile page.  It can then scrape the first 10 connections of my connection but I cannot get it to do anything with the next button.

I select the button using Selenium with the Python code:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.next.carousel-control-disabled")
inputElement.click()
```

If I physically (using the browser and a mouse button) click on this element it loads the next 10 connections BUT when I use the script it gives the following error message.

> Element is not clickable at point (616, 15). Other element would
>   receive the click:

I've tried inspecting the element and I get:

```
<button class="next carousel-control-disabled">Next</button>
```

I think this means there is JavaScript waiting for the element to be clicked.  Does that make sense?  And if so, how can I find out the name of the function and then run that JavaScript?

Comment: I suspect it means that something is covering the element (possibly an overlay), and that if you "clicked" the element, the overlay would receive the click instead.

Comment: So I do I find the other element so I can click the right element?

Comment: You do know that it would be easier to do this with the API? https://developer.linkedin.com/

Comment: No, I didn't know.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @Hisagr I have been unable to work out how to get a list of my connections' connections using the API.  Perhaps you can give some guidance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed `inputElement.click()` to `inputElement.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)` and it is working.

If anyone cares to explain the difference between the two I am interested.

Comment: Not any more - this is from several years ago

Answer (score 1):

**

### Using Selenium and Python to scrape linkedln:

**

```
#Scrolling a full-page
def scroll_till_end():
    try:
        html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
        html.send_keys(Keys.END)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

#moving to next page
def next_page():
    next_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@aria-label="Next"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
    time.sleep(4)
```

It worked for me. Navigate to the connections list using selenium and run the following:

```
 pages_to_scrape=input('Enter the number of pages to scrape:')
 for i in range(pages_to_scrape):
    scroll_till_end()
    get_profile_of_a_page() # profile scrapping function!
    scroll_till_end()
    next_page()
    time.sleep(4)
```